# Matlab basic data graphing

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, vectorization

I'm very new to matlab and need some help finding the correct syntax to do a simple data graphing task. I have a script that analyzes a wave form and saves a six point vector (its value is <3791x6 double>) called features. I need to go through the values in the fifth data space, record whether or not they are above a certain threshold, then graph the results (time vs. above/below threshold).

Here is the basic pseudo code. What is the proper Matlab syntax?

```
create a time vs. boolean vector 'threshold'
fifth column of 'features' equals new vector 'data'
for each value in 'data'
     if (data[index] > threshold value) threshold[index] = true
     else threshold[index] = false
graph(threshold)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of the loop and if condition, try:

`data=features(:,5);`

`plot(data(data>threshold));`

Comment: OP doesn't want to graph only those values above the threshold - they wants to graph both but identify which are above and which below. In addition it needs to be plotted against time.

Comment: sorry, you are correct I meant plot(data>threshold). as you also wrote, this will yields a vector of length(data) with 1 for true and 0 for false.

Comment: Much more elegant than I thought it would be

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
vtime = 1:length(features(:, 5));
plot(vtime, features(:, 5) > threshold, '.');
```

Change `vtime` to be your time vector if that's distinct.